# Executing procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL workbench 6.3 .There is a problem while after trying to execute the procedure for inserting rows, it gives result of all fields 0.Why it does not set the right values of fields that I give for executing?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Actually I just want to know that after executing a stored procedure with parameters what means zeros inserted in table fields,does it mean that procedure is executed with success?

Comment: If you wanted to set those fields to 0, then yes. Otherwise, no.